# Hide application on listings on Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android application on market, I had some patent issue so I need to remove from android market temprorily. I unpublish my application but It shows on top free listings.

anyone know how to remove from listing until I made changes against to patent issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its gone itself in an hour. so just needed some time.